# How do I edit an Imported List?

Tags: list, document-library, csv

I've imported an CSV file as a list to SharePoint.  I need to update the links in the list now since the links in file  mapped to another CMS.  How can I edit this list now that it's in SharePoint?  Should I import it to a library instead of list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Quick Edit option allows you to update the links in a spreadsheet format easily.
Let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Murali for the response.  I was able to enable inline editing from the Modify View screen.  That enables me to edit the list, line by line.  The next step will be to automate this process so that all links will align with the documents that have been moved to SharePoint.